# <a> works for only a small part of an image?

Tags: html, css, image

The question doesn't describe this pretty well.
So I got three small images that are suppose to change on hover and work as a link, but it ''detects'' the hover only in a small part of the image. If I drag my mouse to the bottom of the image link, it's not even clickable, so the link only works in the top part of the image.

See for yourself:
http://jsfiddle.net/M3LC9/ (JSFiddle doesn't like pictures..)

```
<div class="kielet">
 <nav>

 <!--Englanti-->

 <a href="en_index.html"><img class="icon" src="iconit/en.gif" title="in english" onmouseover="this.src='iconit/en_hover.gif'" onmouseout= "this.src='iconit/en.gif'"></a>

 <!--Ruotsi-->

 <a href="swe_index.html"><img class="icon" src="iconit/swe.gif" title="på svenska" onmouseover="this.src='iconit/swe_hover.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='iconit/swe.gif'"></a>

 <!--Venäjä-->

 <a href="ru_index.html"><img class="icon" src="iconit/ru.gif"  title="По русски" onmouseover="this.src='iconit/ru_hover.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='iconit/ru.gif'"></a>
 </div>
```

---

```css
.kielet {
top:0px;
width:100%;
background: black;
right: 0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding:0px;
}

.kielet nav {
right: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
text-align: right;
}

.icon {
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
right: 0px;
margin: 20px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
display:inline;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any image in your fiddle ;)

Comment: jsFiddle *does like* pictures, but you have specified wrong URIs. `iconit/en.gif` obviously doesn't exist on their servers.

Comment: Well what would exist on their servers? You could always copy the HTML and CSS to your desktop and try it with your own images :)

Comment: That's why you use jsFiddle and not just the code here, nobody will search suiting images for your question.

Comment: I get it now. Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have your images set to display as `inline`. This will make them adhere to any `line-height` defaults a browser may have set on your `a` element, keeping your `a` element at a smaller height. This can be visualised in Chrome's Element Inspector:

[image: inline example]

To change this, simply set the display on your `a` elements to `inline-block`:

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image: inline-block example]

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M3LC9/2/).

*Note that you may want to be a bit more specific with your `a` selector by specifying `.kielet nav a`, for instance, or giving your `a` elements their own `class` identifier.*

Comment: I tried setting all the `a` elements to `inline-block` in both, the whole body, and just inside the Kielet div. Nothing changed.

Comment: @user2907241 are you sure you don't have any extra CSS which may be overriding this?

Comment: Yeah. But my CSS code is like 240 rows so it's possible I missed something on my two checks.

Comment: @user2907241 open your browser's Element Inspector and see which computed styles are being applied to your `a` element(s).

Comment: Oh... My other ´div´ was overlapping it. No wonder it didn't work.

Comment: @user2907241 that's because of the `margin` on your `.icon`. Instead of having `margin: 20px; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0;` on your `.icon`, simply put `margin: 0 20px` on your `a` element. :)

Comment: @JamesDonnely It was that simple? How come I didn't notice that. Thanks.

Comment: @user2907241 happens to all of us from time to time. :) Please remember to mark the answer which helped the most as accepted when you get the chance!

Comment: None of these really fixed my problem. But you helped me the most so. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `display` property to `display:inline-block`

```
.icon {
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
right: 0px;
margin: 20px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
display:inline-block; <----
padding: 0px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/CZAmb/)

Comment: This will not work properly in some browsers. The `a` element will still be set to display `inline` regardless of the `img` display.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't implement your hover-state with javascript and `<img />`

You can easily do this with **CSS**.

### HTML

```
<div class="kielet">
    <nav>
        <!--Englanti-->
        <a href="en_index.html" class="icon icon_en" title="in english">&nbsp;</a>
        <!--Ruotsi-->
        <a href="swe_index.html" class="icon icon_swe" title="på svenska">&nbsp;</a>
        <!--Venäjä-->
        <a href="ru_index.html" class="icon icon_ru" title="По русски">&nbsp;</a>
    </nav>
 </div>
```

### CSS

```
.kielet {
    background: black;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

a.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    heiht: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

a.icon_ru { background: url(http://placehold.it/16x16/ffc) center no-repeat; }
a.icon_ru:hover { background: url(http://placehold.it/16x16/ff0) center no-repeat; }
a.icon_en { background: url(http://placehold.it/16x16/cff) center no-repeat; }
a.icon_en:hover { background: url(http://placehold.it/16x16/0ff) center no-repeat; }
a.icon_swe { background: url(http://placehold.it/16x16/fcf) center no-repeat; }
a.icon_swe:hover { background: url(http://placehold.it/16x16/f0f) center no-repeat; }
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/jYqEG/)**

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Whoever upvoted this read what I've written ;) My CSS applies to the link element and I said he shouldn't use a `img` element.

Comment: Good point! My mistake, sorry. Regardless, the user may not want these images to be part of the background.

Comment: That may be true, but it's a common solution. The user can provide his `title` attributes in `a`.